# What happened with the Fide online areana?

Tags: online-chess

About a year ago I stumbled on [arena.myfide.net](http://arena.myfide.net) which looked promising , and unique in the ability to get an actual Fide rating. But in that year no progress has been made with the site, and mobile support continues to say "coming soon". Is this site dead? Or are they just really taking their time with it?

Comment: Almost two years later, the site still seems to be in the same shape as before - limited functionality, very small user base, and paid membership for non-basic features. For untitled players it's a good way to obtain (buy) "official" FIDE titles like Arena International Master (AIM), and for FIDE it's a source of extra revenue. If you're looking to play chess online seriously though, sites like lichess and Chess.com offer much better value (both free and paid).

Comment: I agree, although I have a quick comment - chess.com is more of a freemium site.

Answer (score 1):

It is active and the mobile/tablet option is still coming.

Fide Rated tourneys are daily for various time controls.

Comment: I  this on the website I meant more in terms of progress of the site. It looks like it's been in progress and mobile versions have been in the works for a couple years now and nothing seems to be changing and I wonder why that is.

Answer (score 0):

The website is working. You need to download the latest java version on your computer. The arena is an excellent platform to practice. I don’t think any titles can be bought. You have to work hard to get to the AGM level as well.